# Se borran los valores con mas de 5 cifras al dar formato en un input de express

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express

en un input de una plantilla ejs la cual recibe un valor que el usuario debe digitar, al perder el foco debe darsele formato de número, para ello tengo una función que lo hace de manera correcta pero me he dado cuenta que solo lo hace con valores de hasta 5 cifras, ¿qué podrá ser? no requiro que el valor se elimine del input no importa las cifras y no necesito decimales

Este es el código de input:

```
<input type="number" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off"
value="" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" onkeypress="nextFocus('capacidad', 'plazo')" />
```

Ahora, acá de bajo dejo la función formatNumber que por cierto encontré en otra pregunta acá en el foro

```
function formatNumber(num) {
    if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
    console.log(num);
    //if (isNaN(num))       num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    if (cents < 10)
        cents = "0" + cents;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));

    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar algunos ejemplos de entrada y la salida esperada?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema:

El error es que estás asignando un valor *no numérico* a un input de tipo numérico, ya que, si hacemos un `log` en la parte final luego del `for`, verás que los números mayores a 5 cifras tienen 2 puntos como separador de miles, y esto ya no sería un *número* para asignarlo al campo numérico, ya que el input reconoce al primer punto como decimal, y al asignarle un número con 2 puntos, lo reconoce como un texto, y no puede ser asignado al campo:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
  num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
  num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
  num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
  num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
  cents = num % 100;
  if (cents < 10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
  num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
  console.log(num);
  return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="123.456" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" />
<input type="number" value="123.456.789" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" />
```

---

#### Solución:

Una solución sería que el input sea de tipo texto, cambiando a `type="text"`, así permitimos que el valor que nos devuelve `formatNumber` se pueda asignar al campo, ya que el valor devuelto sería en sí una *cadena de texto*.

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
  num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
  num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
  num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
  num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
  cents = num % 100;
  if (cents < 10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
  num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
  console.log(num);
  return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off" value="" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" />
```

---

#### Ajustes en el formato:

También, noto que hay un pequeño problema aquí:

```
num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
```

Entiendo que la idea es remover **todo caracter** que sea un `.` o una `,` para luego formatear un número sin estos caracteres, pero esto solo ocurre para la `,` y no para los `.`, ya que, por ejemplo, si ponemos varios puntos en la cadena, te devolvería `NaN` porque la función está intentando volver a formatear una cadena pero **con esos puntos sobrantes**. Entonces, bastaría con usar `replaceAll` para remover todos los `.` y `,`, de la siguiente forma:

```
num = num.toString().replaceAll('.', '');
num = num.toString().replaceAll(',', '.');
```

---

Sin embargo, lo correcto sería permitir que **solo se ingrese números** en el campo para que la función haga correctamente su trabajo. Podríamos agregar una función que se ejecute mientras vamos escribiendo en el campo, que incluye una expresión regular quien se encarga de detectar todo caracter que no sea un número del `0` al `9` y el `.`, removiéndolos y asignando la nueva cadena al campo de texto:

```
function removerNoNumericos(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
}
```

#### Código final:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
  num = num.toString().replaceAll('.', '');
  num = num.toString().replaceAll(',', '.');
  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
  num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
  cents = num % 100;
  if (cents < 10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
  num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
    num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
  console.log(num);
  return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}

function removerNoNumericos(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off" value="" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" oninput="removerNoNumericos(this)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que quieres agregar separadores e miles, pero tienes una confusión

- `333333333` Esto es un número
- `333.333.333` Esto ya no es un número, es un texto

Por eso no puedes formatear un `input[type=number]` con separadores de miles. A ti te funciona hasta 6 números por que el elemento piensa que es un separador decimal (no de miles), es decir esto `300.100` que sería trecientos y 100 milesima y NO trecientos mil cien.

Si cambias a `input[type=text]` veras como funciona

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
    if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
    console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
    console.log(num);
    //if (isNaN(num))       num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    if (cents < 10)
        cents = "0" + cents;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));

    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off"
value="" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);"  />

<input type="text" placeholder="perder el foco">
```

Por otro lado formatear un número es más fácil usando [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format)

```js
let numero = 3333333;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en').format(numero)); //3,333,333  <- con comas
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es').format(numero)); //3.333.333 <- con puntos
```

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil saber que es correcto, ya que no das ejemplos de entrada vs salida esperada, creo que hay dos errores, uno es el que te mencionan del `type` del `input`, y el otro está en tu `regex`, con el que quitas las comas, si no estoy entendiendo mal tu código, esperas recibir algo como "$400.234,80" y devolver "400234.80", si es así, debes modificar tu regex que quedaría así:

```
num = num.toString().replace(/\$/g, '');
```

Finalmente tu código sería:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
    if (num == 'Infinity') return '&#x221e;';
      console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$/g, '');
      console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace('.', '');
      console.log(num);
    num = num.toString().replace(',', '.');
      console.log(num);
    //if (isNaN(num))       num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    if (cents < 10)
        cents = "0" + cents;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + '.' +     num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));

    return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + num);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="capacidad" id="capacidad" placeholder="" min="0" 
    maxlength="13" class="border border-info mb-1 form-control" required autocomplete="off"
    value="" min="0" onblur="this.value = formatNumber(this.value);" 
    onkeypress="nextFocus('capacidad', 'plazo')" />
```